# Increase stack size in mac os x Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, stack

For a C++ command line application, I need to increase the stack size, which I do with

```
-Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000,-stack_addr,0xc0000000
```

when I use gnu g++. Now I am learning Eclipse CDT, but do not realize how can I pass this linking option for the automatically generated makefile, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project properties->C/C++ Build->Settings and on the right table select GCC C++ Compiler and you'll see the All Options: where you can insert your options.